# Which SD to use in z-test for proportion in population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, standard-deviation, standard-error

**Background:**

I am testing the prediction ability of games in a league season and as a naive approach would like to check if the proportion of correctly predicted games is > 0.5 and statistically significant.

To achieve that - I sampled ~100 games for every season over few years and the corresponding predictions and now I have the proportions of predicted games for each season.

**The Question:**

My description above is analogous to a sample of 100 coin flips and I would like to test the hypothesis:

let p represent the proportion of correctly predicted games (win/lose)

$H_0$: **p = 0.5**

$H_1$: **p > 0.5**

Now, to calculate the appropriate z-value I would use the following formula: **(sample proportion - expected proportion 0.5) / SE**

My question is which is the appropriate **SE** to use here and **why**?

My options are:

1. I can calculate the **SE** by using sample **SD** and dividing it by $\sqrt{n}$ - which I understand is the case when we actually assume we don't know the actual distribution (**P~binom(n, ?)**) - but in that case it feels to me like the null hypothesis is wrong because it assumes that **P~binom(n, 0.5)**
2. I can calculate the **SE** by using theoretical **SD** and dividing it by $\sqrt{n}$ - which I understand is the case when I assume I actually know that the distribution is **P~binom(n, 0.5)**.

However, according to all resources available I see that the first option is the one I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hypothesis test

You should be using the null effect hypothesis as the standard for your standard deviation.

The reason is: You want to know whether your result is an anomaly with respect to the distribution when there would be no effect.

Below you see this distribution for the case of sampling 100 games.

This is an *exact* distribution. It is the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), and in fact you could compute the p-values exactly. The computation with standard deviations is an approximation of the binomial distribution with the Gaussian distribution, but for low numbers like 100, this is not very neccesary.

[image: example]

---

#### Confidence intervals

In the case of computing confidence intervals, the standard deviation computed according to the observations is used. This is an approximation. It can be done because the standard deviation $\sqrt{n p(1-p)}$ does not change that much for small differences in $p$. For instance if you observe 60 cases it is $\sqrt{100 \cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.6}\approx 4.9$ which differs only a little from the $\sqrt{100 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.5}\approx 5$.

Why do we use the precise formula for the hypothesis test but not for the confidence interval?

The difference between the confidence interval and the hypothesis test is that the confidence interval expresses the *range* of values in which a hypothesis test would not be rejecting. So you would have to use the precise formula for each individual point in the entire range, which requires a complicated formula (instead of simply plus minus some constant times the standard error/deviation with the approximate formula). In the case of the hypothesis test you only use a single point as comparison (e.g. in your case p=0.5) and it is easy to use the precise formula.

Computing the confidence interval with the standard deviation/error based on the observed probability or the hypothesised probability is the difference between [the Wilson score interval and the Wald interval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation